# Approving requests after cap reached

Tags: feature-request, documentation

After a certain amount of changes to documentation, you cannot edit anymore. You are instead given a message

> You cannot review anymore changes today

If you have requests for improvement that get responded to after your final change, you cannot approve or reject the changes.

The feature request I'm putting forward is that responses to suggestions for improvement be immune to the change cap. There's not much point getting pinged if you can't do anything about that ping when you get it.

Comment: I forget... can you approve a suggested edit to your question or answer after you've run out of edit approvals for the day?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the behavior should be consistent.

Comment: Yes, @TylerH - if you own the post, you can always approve / reject edits to it (you aren't voting either).

Comment: As a slight alternative to this, perhaps there could be a privilege that is unlockable which ups the number of reviews you can do? Since much of the privileges on SO are based on trust, it might make sense.